# Taking advantage of Jetblue sale when I already bought ticket?

Tags: air-travel, cancellations, jetblue

A few months ago I bought a Jetblue "Blue" ticket to JFK on 10/31 for $120. Today Jetblue emails me a sale where that same ticket to JFK on 10/31 is $31.

Is there any way (*or trick)* where I can take advantage of this price even though I've already bought the ticket?

I don't think cancelling is worth it because the fee would just eliminate any savings. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Can you shift the date of your current ticket?  Or is that also cost prohibitive?

Comment: We can't answer without knowing the exact type of your existing ticket. Sometimes airlines are willing to _price protect_ as a goodwill gesture in this situation, but I have never heard of their doing so for a ticket that was months old. More like days.

Comment: does the sale require a promo code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to take advantage of this sale.

Answer (score 4):

The policies for price drops vary dramatically depending on the airline and when you purchased your ticket.

For most US airlines, if the price drop occurs within 24 hours of you booking, you can generally just cancel your original booking and rebook at the lower price - but that's not he situation here so that doesn't help you.

Beyond 24 hours, some airlines have specific policies around price drops.  In JetBlue's case, within 5 days of booking they will issue a credit if a price drops and you contact them.  Beyond that 5 days, they will still issue a credit, however it is treated as a change and thus the change fee will be taken from the value of the credit.  The change fee will depend on the specific ticket, but will likely be more than the difference in this case, so probably not worth it.

Other airlines have different policies.  For example, United Airlines will give a credit minus a $50 fee if you contact them within 30 days of booking.  Southwest will give you a credit for the full amount due to their lack of change fees for any booking.

Keep in mind that the cheaper fare may also have different conditions, such as not including carry-on bags, having a higher cancellation fee if you do need to make a change, etc.  Again this will depend on the airline and whether they offer different fare types.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way (or trick) where I can take advantage of this price
>   even though I've already bought the ticket?

Typically not, but that depends a lot on the details  and fare rules of your original ticket. If it's a fully refundable ticket (unlikely) you can return for cash. If it's a flex ticket you may be able to shift the date (back and forth). have the change fee waived and cash in on the current fare difference.

Most likely the change fee will be prohibitively expensive. Read the details for your fare rules,

Answer (score 0):

According to [this travel article on How to Reprice a JetBlue Flight When the Fare Decreases](https://thepointsguy.com/guides/how-to-re-price-a-jetblue-flight-when-the-fare-decreases/) Jet Blue allows a five day grace period to get a credit voucher or points back on price drops, which is better than most US domestic airline policies.

Also noteworthy, having a Jet Blue Mosaic status allows you to get a credit/refund anytime, with no expiration or time limit up to departure.

You can always try to call them and negotiate a deal, but since it's been months, you may not be eligible without a rescheduling fee.

Comment: This is nice, but only valid within 5 days from purchase, and excludes sales - two reasons why it isn't applicable here.